# Cannot convert return expression of type 'SessionDataTask' to return type 'URLSessionDataTask'

Tags: swift, fbsdk

I'm not anymore able to use `URLSession.shared.dataTask` with the last `FBSDKCoreKit` and `FBSDKLoginKit` update.

```
struct Networking {

    func customDataTask(urlRequest: URLRequest, completion: @escaping (Result<Data, NetworkError>)->()) -> Foundation.URLSessionDataTask {
        let urlRequest1 = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "Your url/API links here")!)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest1) { (data, response, error) in
            print("TEST")
        }
        return task
    }
        
}
```

An error:

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'SessionDataTask' to return type 'URLSessionDataTask'.
> FBSDKCoreKit.URLSession:3:15: Found candidate with type 'SessionDataTask'

Comment: Confirming the issue in v9.2.0. Rolling back to v9.1.0